# AJAX to send a JS variable to a PHP file (and then to DB)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

**What I am trying to do**:

- I have a ready made HTML5 game incorporated onto my website - [Link to game](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-game-tutorial-make-a-snake-game-using-html5-canvas-jquery)
- Using this game, I want to now implement a high score board and display it on the same page.
- Example, if I am logged in as Conor, Conor goes to `snake_game.php` where the game is located. He gets a score of three, I need the value of three, which currently is assigned to a JavaScript variable, to become a PHP variable so that I can store it into a table called `high_scores` in my database.
- Then, once the data is in my database, I can start showing the results on the high score variable and update the data when needed.

**Problem(s):**

- I understand that I have to use AJAX to achieve this, but I have never used AJAX before.

**Resources**:

`snake_game.php` is where the container is located where the game is displayed, as well as the high scores div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div class="game_canvas">
         <canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>  
         <script src="javascript/snake.js"></script>
     </div>
     <div class="high_scores" >
         High scores:             
     </div>  
</div>
```

`snake.js` is where all the JavaScript is found to create the game. All the JavaScript is available to view in the link above.

**What I have tried**:

From the game's JS, I believe the score is kept in a var called score - `var score;` - Knowing this, I have tried the below approach in an attempt to get . I have tried to watch a few tutorials online and have come up with this (located in `snake_game.php`):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateScore ()
        {
            var score = $('score').val();
            
            $.post('snake_game.php', {postscore: score}, 
            function () 
            {
                $('high_scores').html(data);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

and then PHP code:

```
<?php    
$new_highscore= $_POST['score'];    
echo json_encode($new_highscore);    
?>
```

I believe the following get's data from the JS? But I am not sure, nor do I think it is the correct way to approach this.

Any/all help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `$('score').val();` should probably be `$('#score').val();`. You need to put `#` before an ID in a selector. `$('score')` looks for an element like `<score>`.

Comment: And `$('high_scores')` should be `$('.high_scores')`. You put `.` before a class name.

Comment: your `$.post` success callback should also have a parameter, `function(data)`. Right now looks like your `.html(data)` is using an undeclared variable.

Comment: @Barmar - `$('#score').val();` as you have mentioned, `#` is needed for ID selectors. But just to clarify in my case `score` is from the `snake.js` file - `var score;` - Do I still need it as `$('#score').val();`

Comment: If the score is in a Javascript variable, you don't need to get it from an element.

Comment: @David784 - I'm sorry, not quite sure what you mean and where? Apologies, I'm new to this.

Comment: @Barmar - So should I implement `$('#score').val();`? How would I get the var score data in php?

Comment: If the score is in a DOM element, then that's how you get it. If it's not in a DOM element, you don't need that. I was just fixing the syntax of your jQuery code, not commenting on the logic.

Comment: `function (data) { $('.high_scores').html(data); });` You were using `data` but you never defined it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access 'score' outside the "ready" function. If you want to implement things the way you were thinking above, you'll have to add a global reference to score, though I'll warn you that's generally frowned upon.

```
// Make a global reference to score 
var score; 

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Canvas stuff
    var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = $("#canvas").width();
    var h = $("#canvas").height();

    //Lets save the cell width in a variable for easy control
    var cw = 10;
    var d;
    var food;
    //var score; THIS NOT NEEDED ANYMORE.
```

You're better off adding your function with the Ajax call within the ready() function just like the code from the tutorial. The way the game works is everytime you run into a wall, the game resets itself by calling the "init" function. To do what you're wanting, before the score gets reset to zero, you want to send it to the server. See below for an idea:

```
function init()
    {
        d = "right"; //default direction
        create_snake();
        create_food(); //Now we can see the food particle

        // Before resetting the score below, send the user score
        // to the server
        sendScoreToServer(score);

        //finally lets display the score
        score = 0;

        ........
```

---

### EDIT:

Freddy, here's the simplest Ajax demo I can give you. You need to study this and fiddle with it until you understand what's going on. After you understand this demo below, you should be able to figure out how to do what you want above. YOU WILL NEED TO EDIT THE <SCRIPT> FILE PATHS AND AJAX URL TO AJAXDEMO.PHP IN MY EXAMPLE FILES TO MATCH YOUR SYSTEM.

**In some HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="score" id="scoreBox"><button id="sendScore">Send Score to Server Running PHP</button>
    <div id="result">The result from the server will be placed here...</div>
    <script src="/resources/js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/ajaxDemo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajaxDemo.js file:**

```
// This function uses AJAX to send the score from the HTML page running javascript to a web server running PHP.
function sendScoreToServer(theScore) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/ajaxDemo.php",
        data: { score: theScore },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('#result').html('The score returned by the server is: '+response.scoreDoubled);    
        }
    });   
}

// Once the HTML page finishes loading, this binds a 'onClick' event to the button that causes it to trigger the sendScoreToServer function.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#sendScore').on('click', function() {
        var score = $('#scoreBox').val();
        sendScoreToServer(score);
    });
});
```

**In ajaxDemo.php file on the server:**

```
<?php
$result = [];
$result['scoreDoubled'] = $_POST['score'] * 2;
echo json_encode($result);
```

**Final Encouragement:**
It sounds to me like you might be slightly confused regarding front-end code vs. back-end code and what the difference is. Just remember that Front-End code runs on the USER'S computer. So when you visit that game tutorial website and it loads the Snake game... that game is running on YOUR computer. Back-End code (PHP is a back-end language) is code that runs on a web server... meaning generally NOT on your computer. By running a web server on your machine with "localhost", you are essentially having your PC 'pretend' to be a web site so you can quickly test and develop your application. Thus any Ajax calls to 'localhost' never have to leave your machine. HOWEVER, in a normal usage environment, an Ajax call would be sending a request over the internet to some remote server such as www.MySite.com. MySite.com would then process the info sent to it using PHP or some other language, then send a response back, which gets processed by the "success" function attached to the ajax request. The "success" function (commonly called a 'callback' function) then updates the HTML page with some result based on what the server sent back.

Comment: Hi, thank's for your answer. I understand your approach, but is this do-able using PHP? For example your approach is sending data to the server  using JavaScript, right? Apologies if I am misunderstanding anything

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would not do this in vanilla php but of course you can.

Things to note:

1) You're not passing your response data into your call back method in your jQuery post

2) you aren't selecting anything with jquery

```
        $.post('snake_game.php', {postscore: score}, 
        function (data) // <-- pass data in here; 
        {
            $('high_scores').html(data); //<!-- you aren't selecting anything here. 
            //if I were you I would make data a json
            //I would have something like
            $('.high_scores').append(data.high_score);
            //actually I have no idea why you even have this callback here

        });
```

3) I don't really understand you're explanation of snake_game.php. It seems like you are trying to use it as both a template and an endpoint. If you are doing things in vanilla php, which I strongly discourage you from doing, you need another php file to handle your post request. e.g. snake_high_scores.php.

```
//in snake_high_scores.php
//this is a really bad way to learn ajax requests. You should use a framework
$new_highscore= $_POST['score']; 
//store this score in a db maybe you can pickup the user id from a session cookie

 echo json_encode({data => {high_score => $some_highscore}});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answers I would suggest whenever game loads make the high score available in page (place in a hidden element/input field if you don't want to show to user) then once the game ends then compare the user score with high score if it is greater than current one  then make the Ajax call to php to store in DB.

This works for both per user (make user high score available once user logs in) or global single high score.